# use socket.io on other port

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make chat based on NodeJS and Socket.IO
All the work is good when I run it on the same port 4040

but when I put the source code of socket.io on other port it doesnt work on ie6 and on ie7 & 8 I see the page refreshed every time when get new data

shortly, I have a website based on PHP port 80, I made chat based on nodeJs port 4040

website work fine and the chat also work fine on port 4040

this is the source of socket.io

work fine on port 4040 :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

work but with problemes on ie 6 7 8

```
<script src="http://mywebsite.com:4040/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

***please don't downgrade my question because I know many of you don't understand 100% my question***

Comment: Wow you already know that, still brave enough to post the question... Hmm ;) So which _other_ port are you referring to, any other or just one in particular..

Answer (score 9):

I'm new to `socket.io` and so far I really like what I'm seeing.

I just wanted to point out a small correction to @sdedelbrock's post.

You probably should **not** use (as was recommended):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4040');
</script>
```

Since this will assume the server is also on the same machine (use of `localhost`). This is what some of my DEV's did and when I deployed their code, it wasn't working at all (client page could not find our server).

What I've tried, and it seems to work well, is to let the `host` portion be auto-resolved by the XHR, by ONLY providing the port number.

**Use the following instead**:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect(':4040');
</script>
```

So no matter to which environment I deploy to (ie: DEV, TEST, STAGE or PROD, etc.) it will always resolve the proper host name client side. Which is what we want.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't change the port that way, here is the best way to change the port.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4040');
</script>
```

Here we call the JS file relative to your application, and specify the port in the initialization of the socket.

Comment: you may have change the polling method to JSON-P polling, check [link](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/413)

Comment: example: `  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the socket.io documentation on how to initialize the client: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/